# Let z be a complex number such that $\frac{z-i}{z-1}$ is purely imaginary. Then the minimum value of $|z-(2+2 i)|$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let
z be a complex number such that $\frac{z-i}{z-1}$ is purely imaginary. Then the minimum value of $|z-(2+2 i)|$ is ?

**My approach:-**

$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \\
\left|z-z^{\prime}\right| \geqslant| \ |z|-\left|z^{\prime}\right||
\end{array}
$$
where, $z^{\prime}=2+2 i$
$$
\left|z^{\prime}\right|=\sqrt{8}=2 \sqrt{2}
$$
$Let, \quad z=x+i y$
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\frac{z-i}{z-1} \\
=\frac{\{x+i(y-1)\}\{(x-1)-i y\}}{(x-1)^{2}+(i y)^{2}} \\
=\frac{x(x-1)+y(y-1)+i(x-1)(y-1)-x y}{(x-1)^{2}-(i y)^{2}}
\end{array}
$$
${}{} \frac{z-i}{z-1}$ is purely imagivery
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\text { Hence, } x(x-1)+y(y-1)=0 \\
x(x-1)=-y(y-1) \\
x^{2}+y^{2}=x+y
\end{array}
$$
What to do next?

Comment: I reckon the set of numbers with $(z-i)/(z-1)$ imaginary form a circle. I'd try to find its centre and radius.

Comment: if $x + y \ne 0$, then $x^2 + y^2 = x + y$ is equivalent to $x - y = 1$.

Comment: how? can u explain>??

Answer (score 0):

this last equality shows that $x$, $y$ is on the circle of radius $\frac{1}{2^{1/2}}$ and of center $(1/2, 1/2)$. Also $|z-(2+2i)|= -x-y+8$, using again the last equality you showed. Observe that this is is a continuous function and, as we showed earlier, on a compact set, so indeed there is a minimum. Now use standard multivariable calculus techniques to find critical points and minimum

Comment: Or just use geometry to find the nearest point on the circle to $2+2i$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng yeah that would be much smarter. the closest point lies on the line that (2+2i) and the center of the circle define. thank you

Answer (score 0):

A geometric approach:

$\frac{z-i}{z-1}$ is purely imaginary signifies that $$\arg\left(\frac{z-i}{z-1}\right)={\pi \over 2}+k\pi$$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}.$

Geometrically, locus of point $z$ is the circle with diameter joining $i$ and $1,$ except these two points.
The center is ${1\over2}+i{1\over2},$ the midpoint of the diameter.

The nearest point of this circle to $2+2i$ lies on the line joining $2+2i$ and the center of the circle.
Therefore, the nearest point is $1+i,$ and the minimal distance $\sqrt2.$

[image]